# Prisma: All migrations are already applied

Tags: database, graphql, migration, prisma

Goal: Run DB migrations inside an InitContainer in a Kubernetes cluster to update the DB.

Expected Result: The container should run, with the Prisma migration packaged into the container. Subsequently, the Prisma migrate command should run and update the DB,

```
npx prisma migrate up --experimental
```

At the moment when the DB is empty the container runs, the migrate command is called and I receive the following message,

```
All migrations are already applied
```

Whilst this creates the _Migration table in the DB none of the migrations are applied. If I connected to the DB from my local machine I can run the migrate scripts and everything updates. If I run the migrate script again from within the container I get the following error,

```
Error: There are more migrations in the database than locally. This must not happen. Local migration ids: . Remote migration ids
```

To ensure I was connecting to the DB correctly I ran,

```
npx prisma introspect --print
```

This printed out the DB schema from the database to prove that the connection string baked into the container was actually hitting the right DB.

I am a little stumped now about where the issue might be. Does anyone know how best to debug Prisma migrations or are there any known issues that might have caused this problem?

Comment: Does your container contain the `prisma/migrations/migrate.lock` file? This file should contain your migrations.

Comment: Yes, I have the migrate.lock file.

Comment: This looks as if the `migrations` folder is not present in the container or the CLI can't find it. Can you share the Dockerfile you used to create the image for the container?

Comment: You were right it couldn't see the migrations folder but it was due to a stupid mistake I wasn't going into the Prisma folder before running the commands.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a stupid mistake, I needed to cd into the prisma folder containing the migrations to run

```
cd prisma
npx prisma migrate up --experimental
```